# How to find and modify required assets in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `//= require jquery.ui.selectable` in application.js. Works great, well sort of. I need to customize this method because the fieldset selector is conflicting in my app.

> // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js,
>   which will include all the files listed below.

Where is the file actually stored so that I can modify it?

Comment: In order to customize some function, I would do it in a separate file. Why? Because you probably want to keep your customizations after you updated the JS file with a newer version.

Comment: @MrYoshiji hey thats a great point. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you didn't include that file yourself, you probably have something like `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` in your Gemfile. To directly answer your question, the jquery UI assets (and indeed any assets belonging to a gem) will all be stored in their respective gem directories, which will be dictated by your `$GEM_HOME` environment variable.

For example, in my case, on my Mac using RVM, the location of my jquery UI directory is:

```
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@some_application/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.4
```

with `$GEM_HOME` being `/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@some_application`.

Having said that, I would strongly **not recommend** manually altering the selectors in the javascript files of a gem. The easiest and cleanest approach would be to alter your DOM structure, at least changing the class, id, or other selectable attributes, in such a way as to avoid the conflict you mentioned. If you update your post with more details regarding the conflicting selector, I'm sure we can help you in a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

if `jquery.ui.selectable` is not included via gem, it will be located in the following places

```
 app/assets/javascripts/jquery.ui.selectable.js
 lib/assets/javascripts/jquery.ui.selectable.js
 vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.ui.selectable.js
 vendor/assets/somepackage/jquery.ui.selectable.js
```

if it is in gem , you can just copy `jquery.ui.selectable.js` file from gem repo and customise it and put it in `assets` folder.

NOTE: i assumed `js`, it can also be `coffee.js`